# Stop anchored controls from moving when resizing the form in the designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to resize a form in the designer without moving any anchored controls? I am using winforms in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to know when it is okay to cheat.  Open the form's Designer.cs file and edit the  this.ClientSize property assignment.  That changes the form size but doesn't affect the Location of controls anchored to the right or bottom.

Comment: OOC, is there an easy way to do this from within VS? The designer file isn't normally visible in VS, but perhaps there is a way to see it?

Comment: I can't recall the exact setting offhand, but the Visual Studio settings should have an option somewhere to be able to view both source files in the project explorer for designer components.

Comment: Maury is a vb.net programmer, old versions of VS required clicking the Show All Files solution explorer toolbar button to see the designer file.

Comment: If you have localization active, which means each language can have its own sizes, you won't find it in Designer.cs but in <Form>.resx resp. <Form>.<iso>.resx. Look for 'name="$this.ClientSize"'. Note that these values don't correspond with the ones you see in the designer. They are a bit smaller because they don't include the frame around the client area (title bar, scroll bars).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this ... keep all the controls to default (i.e. Top, Left) as you are in design view and then anchor them in the code in the form_load / activate event.

Comment: We're talking about designing the form, not running it.